# jqxGrid - handle source for dropdownlist - display name, save id

Tags: jquery, jqxgrid

I'm trying to display a dropdownlist in my jqxGrid with data from json source.

The code I have now is (simplified):

```
var dropDownListSource =
{
    datatype: "json",
    datafields: [
        { name: 'name' },
        { term_id: 'term_id' }
    ],
    id: 'term_id',
    url: Ajax.ajaxurl,
    mtype: 'POST',
    data: {
       action: 'get_taxonomy_terms'
    }
    };

    var dropdownListAdapter = new $.jqx.dataAdapter(dropDownListSource, { autoBind: true, async: false });



// initialize jqxGrid
    $("#jqxgrid").jqxGrid(
columns:
    [
    { text: 'Category', columntype: 'dropdownlist', datafield: 'category', width: 177,
        initeditor: function (row, cellvalue, editor) {
           editor.jqxDropDownList({ displayMember: 'name', source: dropdownListAdapter });
        }
    }
    ]           
 });
```

The JSON is:

```
[{"term_id":"17","name":"category name","slug":"nova-kategorie-2","term_group":"0","term_taxonomy_id":"17","taxonomy":"budget-category","description":"","parent":"0","count":"0"}]
```

This code displays the dropdown, but I would need to display the name, and save the term_id.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of what you are looking!

There are many other options! But this is like the built in when you know the dropdownlist source or you can build your own source

http://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-demo/demos/jqxgrid/gridkeyvaluescolumnwitharray.htm?arctic